# Matlab Indefinite Category Axis

Tags: matlab

I'm interested in making a plot that has a category axis (e.g. `set(gca,'YTickLabel', {'A', 'B', 'C'});`)

However, I don't know the number of categories ahead of time.  In fact, the categories are a vector of nonconsecutive numbers that I nevertheless want to plot consecutively as categories.

E.g. Vector = [5 7 9 2 6]

where Vector is a vector of integers and can be of any size.

I want to make an image() of a 2d matrix, where the Y axis has these integers applied to it as labels or categories for each tick.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, here is an example:

```
ydata=[5 7 9 2 6];
Z=rand(size(ydata,2),10); %random numbers where Y dimension is size of ydata
figure
imagesc(Z) %Make the image of Z
set(gca,'YTick',1:1:size(ydata,2)); % Set only ONE tick 
                                    % mark for each value of ydata
set(gca,'YTickLabel', ydata); %Label the tick marks with the values in ydata.
```

Comment: What makes you think that?  I just ran that code and it worked.

Comment: Maybe it's because size(ydata) should actually be size(ydata,2) in this code, since ydata here is a 1xY and the one in my code is a Yx1, I changed it.  But I can copy paste this and it makes the correct figure

Comment: That was it, computers are stupid that way :)  You can use length(ydata) and it will pick the longer index whether it is 1st or 2nd.